# Connect multiple widget signals with one signal handler in PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, signals-slots

I am trying to create simple apllicatin in Python3 using PyQT4. Main window displays several custom made widgets. Each widget contains a QLineEdit widget. Here is some code:

```
def fill_listwidget (self, widget):
    i=0
    for data in dataList:
        item = QListWidgetItem(myListWidget)

        #create my custom widget
        item_widget = Ui_Form("Widget")

        item_widget.lineEdit1.setText(data)
        item_widget.index =i
        i=i+1

        widget.addItem(item)
        widget.setItemWidget(item,item_widget)

        #########
        def temp (self):
            lineEdit_text_changed(self, item_widget)
            print(repr(item_widget))
            print(repr(self))

        item_widget.lineEdit1.textEdited.connect(temp)
        #########

        #item_widget.lineEdit1.textEdited.connect(lambda: (lineEdit_text_changed(self, item_widget)))

def lineEdit_text_changed(self, widget, data="Null"):
    print(widget.lineEdit1.displayText())
```

As you can see I add one signal handler for all widgets because I want to handle these signals in the same way. The problem is that only the last added widget is handled properly. When I modify other widget's "lineEdit1" fields, still the last widget's field is printed.

Here is how it works:
1 I modify first widget's lineEdit
2 Last widget's lineEdit is printed
3 I modify second widget's lineEdit
4 Last widget's lineEdit is printed
...

I assume that no matter which widget's lineEdit is being modified, the lastWidget is being sent to signal handler but I don't know why.

Please tell me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common scoping problem.

The `item_widget` variable in the body of the `lambda` is coming from the *enclosing* scope, rather than the `lambda`'s *local* scope. So each time around the loop, a new signal is created, but the `item_widget` variable just ends up with the last object assigned to it.

To fix it, use a default argument, like this:

```
item_widget.lineEdit1.textEdited.connect(
    lambda widget=item_widget: self.lineEdit_text_changed(widget))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've corrected it like You said but I get an error now: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lineEdit1'. I don't know if it is important but the signal handler is in a different package so my line looks like this now: **item_widget.lineEdit1.textEdited.connect(
    lambda widget=item_widget: path_to_package.lineEdit_text_changed(self, widget))**

Comment: @user1870314. What line is producing the error? Is it happening in `fill_listwidget` or `lineEdit_text_changed`?

Comment: Eroor is produced by: **print(widget.lineEdit1.displayText())** line

Comment: @user1870314. That makes no sense at all, given the code in your question. You must have changed something elsewhere. (NB: use backticks to format code blocks in comments).

Comment: Sorry. I've missed ".setText" function in line `item_widget.lineEdit1.setText(data)` `data` is a string. I'll look for other misspellings.

Comment: If I do `print(widget)` in `lineEdit_text_changed` it prints `data` string changed by my input.

Comment: @user1870314. Do `print(repr(arg))` for *all* the arguments passed to `lineEdit_text_changed`.

Comment: I got: `<__main__.MyForm object at 0x8fb7584>` after `print(repr(self))`,`MyForm` is a class in which I placed `lineEdit_text_changed` ---- `data` modified by my input after `print(repr(widget))` ---- `Null` after `print(repr(data))`

Comment: @user1870314. What are you passing to the `lambda`? Try replacing it with a temporary function so you can print the arguments. Somehow or other you are passing the wrong arguments in, but it is impossible for me to see what you are doing wrong from the code you've posted so far.

Comment: I've edited the code as You suggested. Please take a look at question. Here is the output: `<root.utillities.listitem_ui.Ui_Form object at 0x8d1e1dc>` ----------
`'data'` modified by my input (from proper widget, not last) ------------- root.utillities.listitem_ui.Ui_Form is my path to class generated by PyQT containing widget layout.

Comment: @user1870314. That means that `self` is your 'data'?! What arguments are you passing to `fill_listwidget`? (PS: These comments are getting far too long, so please carefully check all your code to make sure it is working how you intend it to).